# Java UDF not returning expected result while called inside hive queries

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hql, udf

When I call a java UDF inside hive, it returns inconsistent result than the one returned in IDE (sorted in the same order as string provided). The UDF is created to removed duplicates from a string and return the output in same order but in lowercase.

E.g.:

```
Sony+sony+E2312+xperia+sony => sony+e2312+xperia
```

while executing inside IDE, it returns the correct value (as above) but when called from Hive console, it returns:

```
e2312+sony+xperia
```

UDF code:

```
package com.javaudf.hive;

import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

    public class processDeviceModel extends UDF {
        private Text result = new Text();
        private String delimiters = "[-+\\s*_=|;:]";
        public Text evaluate(Text input) {
            String dmModel = new String();
            if (input == null || input.getLength() == 0) 
                return null;
            else
                dmModel = input.toString().trim().toLowerCase();
            String[] parts = dmModel.split(delimiters);
             Set<String> uniqueparts = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
            for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
                uniqueparts.add(parts[i]);
            }
             String str = StringUtils.join(uniqueparts, '+');
            result.set(str);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Found the issue! probably LinkedHashSet lib is missing in hive!